# Show a UIPopoverController from a detail disclosure button in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am creating an application for the iPad, and I want to show an `UIPopoverController` with an arrow pointing to the detail disclosure button for the row it belongs to. I want to do this in the `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method. Currently I have this, with a dummy `CGRect`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Dismiss in the case it shows itself somewhere else
    [addFeedPopup dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    // Set up
    TNSubscribeToFeedController *subscribeToFeedController = [[TNSubscribeToFeedController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubscribeToFeed" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *subscribeToFeedNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subscribeToFeedController];
    subscribeToFeedController.title = @"Subscribe to feed";
    subscribeToFeedController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:nil];
    subscribeToFeedController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:nil];
    /*
     * Note that we use the UINavigationController pure for the nices UINavigationBar.
     */

    // Show in popup
    addFeedPopup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:subscribeToFeedNavigationController];
    addFeedPopup.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 320);
    [addFeedPopup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];

    // Memory
    [subscribeToFeedNavigationController release];
    [subscribeToFeedController release];
}
```

Also, when the `UITableView` is in editing mode, the detail disclosure button is about 60 pixels to the left, since I use this to set up my rows:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"SectionTwoCell"] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Feed %d", indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Description";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.editingAccessoryType = cell.accessoryType;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
//        TWO LINES BACK DEAR SO USER        //
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks.

---

Oh, and is it also possible to disable scrolling and disable selecting anything until the `UIPopoverController` is closed (perfectionism)?

Answer (score 9):

To do what you want, you need an accessoryView and setting the accessoryType does not create one. However, it will work if you create a button and set it as the cell.accessoryView.

Create and set the accessoryView when the cell is created:

```
    ...
    UIButton *disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [disclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(discloseDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = disclosureButton;
    ...
```

Replace tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: with discloseDetails:.  This looks much like what you have before so I've only put the changes below:

```
- (void) discloseDetails:(UIButton *)sender {
    ...
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];  // if needed
    [addFeedPopup presentPopoverFromRect:cell.accessoryView.bounds inView:cell.accessoryView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    ...
}
```

If you don't need the cell, it can be made even simpler:

```
- (void) discloseDetails:(UIButton *)sender {
    ...
    [addFeedPopup presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    ...
}
```

Here's what it looks like

[image]