# Show a UIPopoverController from a DetailDisclosureButton that is added by setting the Cell.Accessory

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller, monotouch.dialog, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I use in the same way demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Content_Controls/Tables/Add_a_Cell_Accessory) at Xamarin.

Per the instructions in the sample, I set the `cell.Accessory` to a `DetailDisclosureButton` in the `GetCell` method, like so:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
     (Some code to create/style the cell, etc. See tutorial link.)
     cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

I would like to have a `UIPopoverController` to show when the `DetailDisclosureButton` is tapped. Its anchor needs to be 'attached' to the button.

In order to do this, I'll need to change the `AccessoryButtonTapped` method accordingly, like so:

```
public override void AccessoryButtonTapped (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        uipoc = new UIPopoverController(uivc);
        uipoc.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 300f);
        uipoc.PresentFromRect (tableView.CellAt (indexPath).AccessoryView.Frame, tableView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, true);
}
```

`Uipoc` is a class variable, as is the (still empty) `UIViewController uivc`.

As I understand, `PresentFromRect`'s first parameter determines the UIView the UIPopoverController 'hooks up' to, and it needs the Frame property of that view to do so.

Unfortunately, the way I did it above doesn't work. `cell.AccessoryView` is always null, even though I have set `cell.Accessory` to be the `DetailDisclosureButton`.

The answer [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171637/show-a-uipopovercontroller-from-a-detail-disclosure-button-in-a-uitableviewcell) indicates setting the `cell.Accessory` does not affect `cell.AccessoryView` property (I know it deals with ObjectiveC, but I suppose the same applies to MonoTouch).

Instead, it is suggested to add a `DetailDisclosureButton` manually by assigning a `UIButton`to  `cell.AccessoryView`. However, this would mean I cannot use the `AccessoryButtonTapped` method from the Xamarin sample, would need to create my own eventhandler, and so on.

As an alternative, I have tried cycling through the cell's `Subviews`, and hooking up the popovercontroller like this:

```
uipoc.PresentFromRect (tableView.CellAt(indexPath).Subviews[1].Frame, tableView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, true);
```

However, using `Subviews[0]` and `Subviews[2]`, it doesn't work at all, while `Subviews[1]` gives me strange results - the popup menu always shows right next to the first cell's `DetailDisclosureButton` in the table, no matter which cell's button was tapped.

**My question:**
Is there a way to get the `DetailDisclosureButton`'s view (ergo, the accessory's view), if just the `cell.Accessory` is set to `UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton`?

If not, is the latter solution (adding `UIButton` manually) the only way to achieve what I want? How can I do this in C#/MonoTouch?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to figure out why `AccessoryButtonTapped` isn't working.  What is different from the Xamarin sample?  If you set the `Accessory` on the `UITableViewCell`, and its not `None`, then it should fire that message.  Does the Xamarin sample work for you, if you run it?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers `AccessoryButtonTapped` works, I have no issues with the Xamarin sample. My problem is that just setting the `cell.Accessory` to `UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton` in `GetCell` won't expose the accessory's view anywhere. `cell.AccessoryView` is always null and doesn't seem related to whatever type I choose for `cell.Accessory`. I do need the accessory's view though, to hookup the UIPopoverController to it.

Comment: You can show the popover with just a `RectangleF`, you knew that right?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Yes, but that won't let me show the UIPopupViewcontroller with its arrow pointing to the DetailDisclosureButton, since I don't know the button's location. Your comment did give me an idea though :). See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddling I found a somewhat ugly but working workaround:

```
public override void AccessoryButtonTapped (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    uipoc = new UIPopoverController(uivc);
    uipoc.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 300f);
    uipoc.PresentFromRect (new RectangleF(cell.Frame.Right - 40f, cell.Frame.Y, cell.Frame.Width, cell.Frame.Height), tableView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right, true);
}
```

Instead of needing the position info from the accessory's `Frame`, I just use the info of the `cell` itself and subtract 40 from its right side. This will show the `UIPopupViewcontroller` on the left of the `DetailDisclosureButton` in that cell, with its arrow pointing to it. Obviously, you need to subtract (or add) 40 for the right dimension, depending on which `UIPopoverArrowDirection` you choose.

I doubt this is the correct way, though I suppose I'll stick to it unless someone comes up with a better suggestion.

Comment: I would think this is fine.  Probably not an easy way to grab hold of the underlying `UIButton` without looping through `Subviews`.  This seems cleaner than trying to "find" the button in the tree of UI controls.